# Replacing a value in a text file only replacing the last number?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to edit the height in a games config (.txt) and when I do I will only replace the last number. I believe it to be because of the value being a float. For example, `[height = 0.11]` but the remove function will take in int's?

In the text file: `height= 0.11`

Once the new height has been written (0.2): `height= 0.10.2`

The code I currently have :

```
    string text = File.ReadAllText(carDataFile + "\\steamapps\\common\\Car Mechanic Simulator 2015\\cms2015_Data\\Datacars\\car_BoltHellcat.txt");
    const string Pattern = @"height= (?<Number>[\d\.])";
    Match match = Regex.Match(text, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        int index = match.Groups["Number"].Index;
        int length = match.Groups["Number"].Length;

        text = text.Remove(index, length);
        text = text.Insert(index, height.ToString());

        File.WriteAllText(carDataFile + "\\steamapps\\common\\Car Mechanic Simulator 2015\\cms2015_Data\\Datacars\\car_BoltHellcat.txt", text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by replacing the entire `[height= 0.11]` value rather than just trying to replace the last set of digits.  I think the issue is in trying to determine which group has the correct match and the correct index/length.

```
string text = "stuff before [height= 0.11] stuff after";
string height = "height= 0.2";
const string Pattern = @"height= (\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    int index = match.Index;
    int length = match.Length;

    text = text.Remove(index, length);
    text = text.Insert(index, height.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Outputs:

```
stuff before [height= 0.2] stuff after
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had some sort of "Writers block" and just couldn't think.

Comment: No problem.  If this works for you you can accept this as the answer.

Comment: So I've tried to adapt it to my need but now it's not editiing the text file?
Code: 
http://pastebin.com/qrwS33Q7

Comment: Post the content of the actual file you're working with,

Comment: Sorry, I've been ill the past few days. What is it you want? The .sln file?